# Facebook share button on java swing

Tags: java, facebook, swing, facebook-like, share

I have a java swing application and a facebook page I created for distributing the application. I have created a jButton to redirect to the facebook page but now I need a button to be added on jFrame whick share the facebook page page directly being on the jFrame. And also a like button. So the users dont have to visit the facebook page. Please show me a path to get this done in anyhow. Please consider that I'm still learning these things.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The social media sites are providing APIs and by using these APIs, you can add some features of these sites to your java application. There is a good example, which shows you to use facebook share button on java.

[Facebook integration](http://www.devx.com/Java/how-to-integrate-facebook-and-twitter-with-java-applications.html)